# Python 3 modules: user configurable relative directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

So I have a convention (perhaps it is a bad one) that I structure my python packages somewhat like this:

```
<py-pkg>
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    subpkg/
        __init__.py
        module.py
    ...
```

where in `settings.py`

```
'''-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DIRECTORIES AND FILES
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'''
MODULE_DIR      = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR     = os.path.join(MODULE_DIR, '..')
DATA_DIR        = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'data')
SOURCE_DIR      = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'source')
DERIVED_DIR     = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'derived')

# other relevant relative paths to default files / paths
```

While this works often quite well for me, it may be the case where say the user wants to update `DATA_DIR` and all dependent paths.

How could I make that configurable?

Comment: Do you mean like using env variables? `DATA_DIR = os.environ.get('MY_PROJECT_DATA_DIR', os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'data'))`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta ideally without having to use environment variables, so staying strictly in the python interpreter

Comment: What does that mean? I mean: do you want your users to simply edit the source files? You could do `try: from my_project_user_conf import USER_CONFIG except ImportError: USER_CONFIG = {}` and get the values from there. If the users want they can just create the module `my_project_user_conf` and put it somewhere in the `PYTHONPATH`. Or you can use [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) and let the users write an ini file somewhere in their home... you did not specify exactly how the users should be able to configure the application

Comment: Ideally they wouldn't modify the source code. Like the first line might set `DATA_DIR` and then they import `DERIVED_DIR` which is updated by the `DATA_DIR` they set